# Running pg_dump with nohup in the background with sudo privileges

Tags: postgresql, psql, nohup, pg-dump, pg-restore

I want to dump a rather large database (1 tb) using pg_dump. Problem is via vpn, it timesout. So i want to run it via nohup and have had no luck. This is the base command:

```
sudo pg_dump -U postgres -F d -Z 9 -h <<host>> -p 5432 -d <<Db>> --column-inserts --data-only -n admin --verbose -f  /data/dump1 -j 15
```

Things i have tried
1)putting nohup in the beginning and & in the end
2)Putting command in a bash file and trying to run the bash
3)Various permutations and combinations(like putting sudo before nohup)

It just says Exit 1 and nothing gets written to the nohup log file. I want to see the verbose output there.

Comment: I don't think `--column-inserts` can be used with `-F d -Z 9`. Former implies plaintext SQL statements, letter a custom, compressed postgres format.

Comment: Do you actually want to run this as root, are you just adding sudo in an attempt to get nohup to work?

Answer (score 0):

The `nohup` command is only meant to ignore the `SIGHUP` sent by the OS when the user disconnects. You can do something like:

```bash
$ sudo nohup pg_dump -U postgres -F d -Z 9 -h $host -p 5432 -d $db --column-inserts --data-only -n admin --verbose -f  /data/dump1 -j 15
```

And after the process starts and you input your password for `sudo`, send a CTRL-Z (`^Z`) and run `bg && disown` to resume and detach the process from your terminal.